# How can I use co with express?

Tags: node.js, express, co

I'm using express with node and want to use a co/yield patter to wrangle my async callbacks.

The current code looks like this:

```
web.post('/request/path', function(req, res, next) {
    co(function *() {
        let body = req.body
        let account = yield db.get('account', {key: body.account})
        if (!account) {
            throw new Error('Cannot find account')
        }
        let host = yield db.get('host', {key: body.hostname})
        ....

    }).catch(err => {log.info(err) ; res.send({error: err})})
```

This is working really well, but I'd like to be able to simplify the first 2 lines:

```
web.post('/request/path', function(req, res, next) {
    co(function *() {
```

Is it possible to somehow integrate the co(function *() into the first line?  Does express provide support for co() and yielding functions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [co-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-express) along with promises.

Example,

```
router.get('/', wrap(function* (req, res, next) {
    var val;

    try {
        val = yield aPromise();
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }

    res.send(val);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the syntax with an arrow function:

```
web.post('/request/path', (req, res, next) => co(function *() {
        //...
}).catch(err => {log.info(err) ; res.send({error: err})})
```

I don't see any extra benefit to using another package. When async/await hits the shelves, we may see express get an update.

On a side note, making your own co-express is rather simple:

Consider 'co-express/index.js'

```
module.exports = generator => (req, res, next) => require('co').wrap(generator)(req, res, next).catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

And now:

```
var coe = require('./co-express');
web.post('/request/path', coe(function *(req, res, next) {
    //...
})
```

This way you've got the latest co package.